# error: Call to a member function startTrans() on a non-object

Tags: php, semantic-web, owl

I am using [pOWL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powl/) to build a content management system of OWL files. I want to be able to `query` the OWL files as well as add new instances and classes. However I am stuck. I need to load the OWL file into an OWLModel using pOWL. So I tried:

```
$base="wine.owl";
$store = new DefaultPOWLStore(ADODB_DB_DRIVER, "localhost", "powl", "root", "password");

$model = ModelFactory::getOntModel('DBModel','RDFS_VOCABULARY', $base);
$model = new OWLModel($store, $base);
$model->load('wine.owl');

$model -> __construct($store, $base);
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function startTrans() on a non-object in C:\Users\xxx\xxx\powl\rdfapi-php\api\model\DbModel.php on line 878
```

The code with the error is:

```
    if (is_a($model, 'MemModel')) {
            if (is_object($model)){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r("!!!!!!!");
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        $this->dbConn->startTrans();
```

I added the second if clause in an attempt to check if `$model` is an object, and it passed the clause. But I am not sure if that is the correct way to check if a variable is an object.

**UPDATE:** The issue seems to be with `dbConn` variable, need to find a way to load the model into the DB for `dbConn` to be defined. Will look tomorrow.

Comment: I don' think that's saying that `$model` isn't an object, but that `$this->dbConn` isn't an object.  If `$this->dbConn` were an object, then `$this->dbConn->startTrans();` would be calling its member function, but it is not, so the code failed at a `call to a member function startTrans() on a non-object`.

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for the comment, I must have literally realised this at the same time as you. I will work on it again tomorrow and update further. keep an eye on it as I will probably need your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got around this as I was trying to load the `OWL` file into the model. I should have loaded the file using`$store`. Here is the code:

```
$modelURI = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#";
$base="wine.owl";
$filename ="wine.owl";
$store = new DefaultPOWLStore(ADODB_DB_DRIVER, "localhost", "powl", "root", "password");

if(!$store->modelExists($modelURI)) {
    $store->loadModel($modelURI, $base);
}

$model = new OWLModel($store, $modelURI);
$store-> putModel($store, $modelURI);
```